# How to remove ' in strings with RegexpTokenizer

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
text="That's some text, you know!"
tokens=[]
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
tokens+=tokenizer.tokenize(text.lower())
```

Currently returns: `text = ['that', 's', 'some', 'text', 'you', 'know']`

I need it to return: Currently returns: `text = ['thats', 'some', 'text', 'you', 'know']` (The "thats" is one word)

Comment: why don't you just remove the `'` with `replace("'", "")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: @hansaplast This is text processing, a simple replace might replace other `'`  which are not apostrophes, which is why they are using nltk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 solutions. Either you want to preprocess your text variable with:

```
text = text.replace("'", "")
```

or you want to match "that's" as a single word with this modification:

```
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'[\w\']+')
```